# Is there a way to display the field's own value in its help_text?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

In my Django app I have a model with a field named URL. I want in its help_text string to show this URL as a link. So that if a value exists in this field, I could go into the object and click the help text below the URL field.

How can this be done?

Comment: if you can grab __init__ while it's initialising you could dynamically change it.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to is override it manually;

```
form = MyForm()
form.fields['my_field'].help_text = form.cleaned_data.get('my_field').url
# wrap in try since CD may not exist.
```

You could also build a custom form field that knows how to set its help_text based on its own value..

```
class MyField(forms.AField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.help_text = self.clean(self).my_field_attribute
```

I'm not sure what kind of escaping django does on the help_text field, but simply marking it as `django.utils.safestring.mark_safe` may be enough to get it to render HTML.